# Is the union all numbers divisible by 5 and divisible 3 countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using the method where you determine if this set has the same cardinality as the positive integers **where would you start?** there appears to be *no straightforward equation representing the set that contains all divisors of 3 and 5*, can this be done with those diagonal charts?

insight into **where to start or what to learn** would be helpful

Comment: should have said "Is the union of all numbers divisible by 5 and divisible by 3 countable?"

Comment: First, note the set is at most countable, being a subset of the integers. Now observe it is infinite. Conclude it is countably infinite.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I suspect OP wants to see the construction of the bijection and already knows it is countably infinite.

Comment: You have the union of two countable sets $5\Bbb Z$ and $3\Bbb Z$!

Comment: bijection with the union of the 5 and 3 set seems very ugly, is there a pattern or visual way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cantor Bernstien theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

The canonical injection $X \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, together with $\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow X$ defined by $n \mapsto 5n$, where $X$ is the set of all integers divisible by 5 or 3, fulfills the requirements for the CBT.

Comment: does this then skip the divisible by 3 set?

Comment: Not really, the bijection comes from the the two injective maps together.

Comment: The CBT is very useful for rigorously establishing a bijection of sets.

Comment: What is the CBT?

Answer (score -2):

Hint: Can you construct a bijection from the natural numbers to your set?  If you can, what does that tell you?

Comment: I don't think the OP needs to be reminded of the definition of cardinality...

Comment: That's just it, there is no straight forward equation that doesn't involve extensive decimal approximations